# Modifying regex to not allow spaces

Tags: regex

I have this regex that matches any string that contains one or more letters followed by one or more numbers

`[A-Za-z].*[0-9]`

I'd like to modify this to not allow spaces, which looks like can be done with `[^ ]`

I've tried several different ways to modify my existing regex, but nothing seems to work, it always allows spaces in my string. I've tried these:

`[A-Za-z].*[0-9]+[^ ]`

`[A-Za-z].*[0-9].+[^ ]`

`[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[^ ]`

What's the right way for me to do that?

Comment: `^[A-Za-z][^ ]*[0-9]$`, `^[A-Za-z]\S*[0-9]$`... Maybe the anchors are not necessary.

Comment: Use a quantifier `+` for the character classes to repeat 1+ times  `^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$`

Comment: It is worth pointing out to the OP that the reason the regexes in the post don't work is that dot `.` matches any character, including a white space character.